# forwarding parameters from variadic function to fixed argument function

Tags: c++, logging, macros

I have a function which takes a variable number of arguments. From this function I want to call functions that take fixed number of arguments,

```
void log(int level, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    int count = 0;
    void *navigator[10] = NULL;

    while ((navigator[count] = va_arg(args, char*) ) != NULL && count < 10) 
        ++count;   //Is this the right way to count no. of arguments passed ?


    fprintf(stderr, "**** No of arguments : %d\n", count);
    fflush(stderr);

    switch (count - 2)
    {
    case 0:
                log_l(level, fmt);
        break;
    case 1:
           log_l1(level, fmt, navigator[0]);  // how would I get arg1 here, 
                                              // I get NULL in the called function)*/
        break;
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .

    };
}
```

I want to know the right way of counting the number of parameters passed and then properly forward them to other fixed parameter functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `va_start` needs to be `va_start(args, format);  // Note change to "format"`.

EDIT: Even with this according to the manpage fro `va_arg` you can't do what you want.

> If there is no actual next argument,
>        or iftype is not compatible with the type of the actual next
>        argument (as promoted according to the default argument pro-
>        motions), the behavior is undefined.

But this is tagged C++ so why not use the C++ idiom: Use streams and an insertion `operator<<` instead of using varargs at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way - you need to pass this information explicitly, e.g. with a count parameter or an explicit 0 as last parameter. Type info isn't passed in any form either.

Comment: You can also pass the information about count and kind of parameters implictly int the "format" parameter. Some functions like `printf` are using it this way.